# ajax show container not animating as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, load

I am writing a plugin for showing ajax content.It is wrapped in a `ajax-content-wrap`.I have applied jquery animate() but not smooth with auto height.And fade() function is also animating.But when i use a specific height animate() works and fadeIn() does not works.

### my html codes are below

```
<div class="ajax-content-wrap">
   <div class="ajax-content-show">
      //here to show contents from external files
   </div>
</div>
```

### My jquery

```
$('.ajax-content-show').animate({height:'200px'}, function(){
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
      $(this).fadeIn('slow').load(url);
    })
});
```

### My css

```
.ajax-content-show{
   padding: 20px 20px;
   display: block;
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to acheive here is a solution:

```
$('.ajax-content-show').animate({
    height: '200'
}, 500, "linear",

function () {
    $('.ajax-content-show').hide(0, function () {
        $('.ajax-content-show').load(url, function () {
            $('.ajax-content-show').fadeIn('slow')
        });
    });
});
```

If not, can you explain (in steps) what you require, first make "div" 200px then fade in "loaded page" or do them both simultaneously?

Note: Don't need to include the 'px' when setting the height property, JQuery assumes pixels as a default.

Comment: actually first i need `inherit` or `auto` height but that is not working smoothly. 2nd things is working now i'v added fadeIn class with animate.css. Now tell me the sol'n of first one

Comment: Why not just replace height: '200' with display: 'block' ?

Comment: If you want to do "dynamic" height first, you will need to load url "hidden" then get the height of div/body. then only begin your animation code and fade once you have the height of the loaded url content, That's the only way to do it. Here is a link (hope it helps): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493825/jquery-set-height-after-load

Answer (score 0):

May this you want ?
See snippet.

```js
$(".ajax-content-show").load("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", function(){
  $(this).slideDown(10000); // change the time, or just remove it if you think too slow.
  $(this).addClass("loaded");
});
```

```css
.ajax-content-show{
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin: 10px 0;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s ease;
  max-height: 500px; /* This just for show that sliding is working */
}
.ajax-content-show.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajax-content-wrap">
   <div class="ajax-content-show">
      //here to show contents from external files
   </div>
</div>
```